# Issues with .bib file and LaTeX

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography

I am trying to add references to my .tex file from my .bib file but I keep receiving the following errors:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "10"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023)
The top-level auxiliary file: 10.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file 10.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file 10.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file 10.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "10".tex

Process exited normally
```

Not sure what to do?

The .aux file is in the folder with the other files.

Comment: Could be better suited for Tex Stack Exchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/